# How do I connect to USB HDD on BT Homehub 3?

Tags: samba

I have a home network, based around a BT Homehub 3.

My understanding is that whilst the BT Homehub 3 is essentially a **Linux** machine, it uses Windows (SMB) networking.

I also have an HTPC based on OpenELEC on the network, and a Sony Vaio on which I use Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 7).

Attached to the BT homehub 3 (via USB) is a 2TB NTFS media storage drive.

The HTPC can see and connect to this just fine, at smb://BTHUB3/USB1, and can stream media from it, as intended.

However I wish to also connect my Ubuntu laptop and the homehub mounted drive. This is proving to be a real pain.

I have tried the following:

- In the browser (Chromium) navigate to `file://192.168.1.254/` (that is the correct IP for the BThomehub, but I get the file list for my laptop.
- In nautilus - click through HOME group - freezes and fails to access "unable to access location".
- In terminal: nautilus `smb://bthub3/usb1` - nothing happens.

Note that the default workgroup for Ubuntu is *WORKGROUP*, but I changed this to *HOME*. I have tried all the above using both variations.

Comment: I just found (in Windows 7) that changing the workgroup name from "WORKGROUP" to "HOME" allows access to the USB drive on BTHUB3. However, the same procedure does not help in Ubuntu. By default, the hub uses the workgroup name "HOME" and this cannot be changed.

Comment: This issue may be related: http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/12-04-Nautilus-Samba-workgroup-domain-lowercase-td5007244.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here

[www.liberiangeek.net](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/how-to-fix-failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-when-file-sharing-with-windows/)

All you need to do is:

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

find the line (~ line 38):

```
workgroup = workgroup
```

(the right hand side workgroup should probably read mshome or home which ever you should have already set it to)

Then on the line below this (line 39) add:

```
name resolve order = bcast host
```

And then restart ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.254/usb1 /mnt/hub_usb --verbose -o user=winuser
```

and blank for the pwd